# Saving Screenshot to android gallary via game

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, screenshot

It takes the screenshot but doesn't show in gallery . the screenshot is saved to android/data/com.company.name/file.name but I want to save it directly to the gallery with filename screenshot

So far, here my code is:

```
public void Capture() 
{
    string filename = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss");
    Application.CaptureScreenshot(filename + ".jpg");
    Debug.Log("captured screenshot");
}
```

Comment: I don't think Unity can access the gallery. You'd have to first add the permission in the manifest, then use some Android native code passing a byte array from Unity to native.

Comment: yes i fixed that in player setting , my problem is that it does not appear in gallary .. i am totally noob , someone plz share some code to try

Answer (score 5):

Look for the answer provided [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/204372/saving-screenshots-to-android-gallery.html) (the second one). It works perfectly.

Here's the final code:

```
protected const string MEDIA_STORE_IMAGE_MEDIA = "android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media";
protected static AndroidJavaObject m_Activity;

protected static string SaveImageToGallery(Texture2D a_Texture, string a_Title, string a_Description)
{
    using (AndroidJavaClass mediaClass = new AndroidJavaClass(MEDIA_STORE_IMAGE_MEDIA))
    {
        using (AndroidJavaObject contentResolver = Activity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getContentResolver"))
        {
            AndroidJavaObject image = Texture2DToAndroidBitmap(a_Texture);
            return mediaClass.CallStatic<string>("insertImage", contentResolver, image, a_Title, a_Description);
        }
    }
}

protected static AndroidJavaObject Texture2DToAndroidBitmap(Texture2D a_Texture)
{
    byte[] encodedTexture = a_Texture.EncodeToPNG();
    using (AndroidJavaClass bitmapFactory = new AndroidJavaClass("android.graphics.BitmapFactory"))
    {
        return bitmapFactory.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("decodeByteArray", encodedTexture, 0, encodedTexture.Length);
    }
}

protected static AndroidJavaObject Activity
{
    get
    {
        if (m_Activity == null)
        {
            AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
            m_Activity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        }
        return m_Activity;
    }
}
```

And you simply call:

```
string path = SaveImageToGallery(picture, "Test Picture", "This is a description.");
```

**EDIT:**
Since you seem really new to Unity I'd suggest learning it first. Anyway here's how you can call the code provided above:

```
public void CaptureScreenshot()
{
    StartCoroutine(CaptureScreenshotCoroutine(Screen.width, Screen.height));
}

private IEnumerator CaptureScreenshotCoroutine(int width, int height)
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(width, height);
    tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
    tex.Apply();

    yield return tex;
    string path = SaveImageToGallery(tex, "Name", "Description");
    Debug.Log("Picture has been saved at:\n" + path);
}
```

Simply add those two methods to your code and call the `CaptureScreenshot()` either from another script, a Unity Button, or anything else...

*Hope this helps,*

Comment: This is C# code here. The Java code is contained in the methods used and you cannot see it.

Comment: i cant call it .. i made       public void captureScreen()
    {
        string path = SaveImageToGallery(picture, "Test Picture", "This is a description.");
    }

Comment: should i attach this script to main camera and then on my button add a trigger event attaching the camra and then what??

Comment: Well it seems you are completely new to Unity: therefore I'd advise you to take a look at the [tutorials](https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials) first. They are well made and will guide you through the basics of the engine. Anyway I edited my answer to give you a complete usage of the code.

Comment: Hope I am not irretating you , this is a native plugin will  it work for FREE UNITY ... i dont have pro unity ,...

Comment: Yes [it will](https://store.unity.com/) ! No irritation here don't worry: SO principle is to help each others ;)