# Saving Screenshot to Android Gallary via AR Apps

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, arcore

so i am working on an ar application for android and i want to make screenshots of my ar scene in runtime and save them in the gallery.
i create my app in unity 2018.1.6f1 with newest vuforia and arcore plugins on a samsung s8.
i am pretty new to ar development and i want to prototype with both plugins and test the features of both plugins in the long run, plus i have basically no clue of programming android native features.

knowing my lack of skill i searched for a solution in other posts and i found this:

[Saving Screenshot to android gallary via game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44756917/saving-screenshot-to-android-gallary-via-game)

the solution in the answer works fine with vuforia but not at all with ar core. at this point i dont know how to make it run in ar core and i need help.

i forgot to mention that it seems that the arcore application is capturing the screen but not saving the image in gallery or any other location i could find.

i hope someone can hint me in the right direction or maybe fix the script.
ty and sry for bad english :)

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

namespace ARCoreDemo
{
public class InAppScreenShotToGallery : MonoBehaviour
{

    protected const string _mediaStoreImageMedia = "android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media";
    protected static AndroidJavaObject _activity;


    public void MakeScreenShot ()
    {
        StartCoroutine (CaptureScreenShot (Screen.width, Screen.height));
    }


    private IEnumerator CaptureScreenShot (int width, int height)
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame ();
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D (width, height);
        texture.ReadPixels (new Rect (0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
        texture.Apply ();

        yield return texture;
        string path = SaveImageToGallery (texture, "Name", "Description");
        Debug.Log("Picture has been saved at;\n" + path);

    }


    protected static string SaveImageToGallery (Texture2D texture, string title, string description)
    {
        using (AndroidJavaClass mediaClass = new AndroidJavaClass(_mediaStoreImageMedia))
        {
            using (AndroidJavaObject contentResolver = Activity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getContentResolver"))
            {
                AndroidJavaObject image = Texture2DToAndroidBitmap (texture);
                return mediaClass.CallStatic<string>("insertImage", contentResolver, image, title, description);
            }
        }
    }


    protected static AndroidJavaObject Texture2DToAndroidBitmap(Texture2D texture)
    {
        byte[] encodedTexture = texture.EncodeToPNG();
        using (AndroidJavaClass bitmapFactory = new AndroidJavaClass("android.graphics.BitmapFactory"))
        {
            return bitmapFactory.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("decodeByteArray", encodedTexture, 0, encodedTexture.Length);
        }
    }


    protected static AndroidJavaObject Activity
    {
        get
        {
            if (_activity == null)
            {
                AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
                _activity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
            }
            return _activity;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You have a Debug.Log-line in your code printing out the location of the saved picture, can you see what that is line is saying?

Comment: i dont know how to get debug data on an android phone and arcore-instant-previewer is bugged on samsung s8 (getting white screen in game view), so i cant use the unity console for debugging + (with vuforia) getting errors that i cant debug androidjavastuff in unity too.

Comment: You can get the debug log from the device using logcat.  see https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat

Comment: I am not 100% on this, but the NatShare API may be able to help you. I believe it can save a recorded video to your device via a file path, and perhaps it will let you do the same for an image.